# mu4e: open PDFs with pdf-tools

Tags: email, mu4e, pdf, pdf-tools

I've just set up `mu4e`, and have noticed that when opening an attachment with the `o` key it will open with `MuPDF`. Pressing `A` `w` to open-with doesen't seem to help either, since it prompts for an external shell command.

I'd like to open PDF attachments with `pdf-tools` instead of `MuPDF`, or at least be able to open with with the open-with function mapped to `A` `w`

Comment: For me, pressing `A` `e`, for "in-emacs", opens the attachment in PDFView. Have you tried that?  Also, `o` `e` works exactly the same.

Comment: You're right! I just tried it with another PDF file, and it worked out the box. I think the test PDF my friend sent me was missing the file extension, and so Emacs was opening the PDF as a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recapping discussion in comments: Pressing `A` `e`, for "in-emacs", opens the attachment in PDFView. `o` `e` works exactly the same.